# Jquery select random cell every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to select one div out of the sixteens and that one needs to change it CSS backgrounds. It also needs to happen every second, so every second a new div is selected from the other ones.

I'm getting stuck with the every second part, this is a part from what I have(not self-made): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RJMhT/)

My HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Random plaatjes</h1>
        <div class="pics">
            <div class="heading">
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatjes 1
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatjes 2
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatjes 3
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatjes 4
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 1
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 2
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 3
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 4
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 1
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 2
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 3
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 4
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 1
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 2
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 3
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 4
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 1
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 2
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 3
                </div>
                <div class="cell" id="cell">
                Plaatje 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

In my way, I want a random id="cell" to be selected every second with an red border or something.
If you guys good help me get to the right way I would really appreciate it! Thanks for the help, and sorry for my bad English(not my mother tongue).

Comment: `id="cell"` 100 times is incorrect markup. ID **must** be unique per page. Imagine 100 people with your same insurance number...

Comment: Grab the collection of `div.cell` then you can use `math.random` to select a cell from the collection.

Comment: And use `setTimeout` to execute it every second

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've deleted it, thank you!

Comment: @scrappedcola I will look it up, thank you for replying!

Comment: @prajmus Yeah I was looking for that function, thank you, I'm going to try it all out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly as others in the comments have stated, having duplicate `id` attributes is invalid so you need to remove `id="cell"` from your HTML.

Secondly, you can achieve this by getting the number of `.cell` elements in the page, then choosing a random number between that and zero. You can then get the element chosen via the `eq()` method. Finally, you can run the code every second using the `setInterval()` function. Try this:

```
function highlight() {
    var $divs = $('.cell').removeClass('highlight');
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length);
    $divs.eq(random).addClass('highlight');
}
highlight(); // run on load
setInterval(highlight, 1000); // then every 1 second afterward
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/RJMhT/2114/)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `id` attributes are **unique**, meaning you may not have more than one element with the same ID.

To achieve what you're wanting you can combine `Math.random()` with `window.setInterval()`:

```
// Timed interval which occurs every 1000 milliseconds
window.setInterval(function() {

    var $cells = $('.cell'), // Get all elements with a class of "cell"
        cellCount = $cells.length, // Determine how many elements there are
        random,
        selected;

   // Generate a random number between 0 and the number of elements
   random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cellCount);

   // Get our randomly selected element
   selected = $cells[random];

}, 1000);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/mmxr7sdg/2/).

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure a random cell is picked when the page is loaded (I'm adding a class "active" in this example - could be something else though):

```
var allCells = $('.cell');  
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * allCells.length);
allCells.eq(index).addClass('active');
```

Then, every second, first remove the active class from whichever cell is active, then add it to another random cell:

```
window.setInterval(function(){

    $('.cell.active').removeClass('active');

    var allCells = $('.cell');  
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * allCells.length);
    allCells.eq(index).addClass('active');

}, 1000);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/fx0m7e3a/